# Can't get container.addView() in Android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I get null values from `container` in Android.

```
@Bind(R.id.container)
ViewGroup container;

private void addUploadToList(String uploadID, String filename) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        View uploadProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_upload_progress, null);
        UploadProgressViewHolder viewHolder = new UploadProgressViewHolder(uploadProgressView, filename);
        viewHolder.uploadId = uploadID;
        container.addView(viewHolder.itemView, 0);
        uploadProgressHolders.put(uploadID, viewHolder);
}
```

I can't get values `container = null`, the exception is:

```
System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
System.err:     at kr.co.composer.callrecord.recorder.CallRecordService.addUploadToList(CallRecordService.java:164)
```

This module I folk from work perfect.

https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/tree/master/examples/app

I want to use `onMultipartUploadClick()` to integrate this into my project to save a file when to uploading successfully.

After line:

`recorder.stop();`

Is this file in my project:
`http://pastebin.com/KATBMTCe`

This file `extends Service` while [in Github responsitory](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service/tree/master/examples/app) extends from `AppCompatActivity`.

This is all problem, I try using code in this GitHub responsitory to auto upload when to call end.

Comment: Is the object(s) you're passing to the addUploadToList initialized properly?

Comment: You haven't initialized the variable "container".

Comment: can you show either **onCreate()** method of ur activity or **onCreateView** if it is a Fragment

Comment: It is a service. @Sanny

Comment: where is the place you initialised the container ?

Comment: @Sanny , I updated all my question to you can easy read.

Comment: @Sanny , can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `container` is not initialized. Initialize it with,

```
WindowManager container = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)
```

So your code will become,

```
private void addUploadToList(String uploadID, String filename) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    WindowManager container = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,// | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;

    View uploadProgressView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.traslucent, null);
    UploadProgressViewHolder viewHolder = new UploadProgressViewHolder(uploadProgressView, filename);    
    viewHolder.uploadId = uploadID;
    uploadProgressHolders.put(uploadID, viewHolder);
    container.addView(viewHolder.itemView, params);
}
```

Comment: I meet error: cannot find symbol method getLayoutParams()

Comment: Thanks @K Neeraj Lal. I try this code, it run ok but seem it don't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). You need to inject the views in your Activity/Fragment.

Activity

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
  ButterKnife.bind(this);
  // TODO Use fields...
}
```

Fragment

```
@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_fragment, container, false);
  ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
  // TODO Use fields...
  return view;
}
```

Comment: Yup, I using Butterknife, but I can't change code like your write.

Comment: I don't why you can't do it!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use service, use [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) with custom event ,listen it from `Activity` and do the downloading jobs in `Activity` as the `MultipartUploadRequest` is `Async`.

**CallRecordService.java**

```
try {
        recorder.stop();
        //emit event
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent("download-event"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I believe you have activity which start that service.Put below code in ur activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....


       //register and listen event
       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new DownloadReceiver(), new IntentFilter("download-event"));

    }


    private class DownloadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // call multipart download function here
        }
    }
```

With that way at least you inject your layout in Activity as normally and can clearly know why `container` is `null` . make sure you have correct id in ur xml layout file.